# Ehcache does not work properly

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

In my app I am using query cache with the following ehcache settings:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="false">  

 <defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="10000000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
    diskPersistent="true"
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="1800"  />

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="0"        
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000"
    eternal="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>
</ehcache>
```

then for my entity I have 2nd level cache like:

```java
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

and my query is like:

```java
getSession().createQuery("from DynamicScenario").setCacheable(true).list();
```

which works fine. However, what I've noticed in the console is that after some update on the table such as update/insert/delete no matter how many times I execute the query again and again hibernate still makes calls to the db to fetch the data although this is registered as memory hit in the jConsole when I monitor ehcache. This lasts about 30 seconds and then on the 31 seconds or so when I execute the query again I can see in the console that there's no call to the db by hibernate and the data comes from the cache. Is there any reason for that? It seems like hibernate should free some resources to invalidate the cache and then rebuild upon a table change and this lasts some time...

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: the table contains barely 100 records..it's not the data issue..I am just testing the behaviour of ehcache..you can try it yourself with the same settings